# Trouble with ng-show and ng-disabled in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple demo HTML page in client side form validation. I'd like to integrate Bootstrap + AngularJS + Jquery,though I'm new to AngularJS.

I don't know why ng-show and ng-disabled not working as expected.The submit button should be disabled when any of the input controls is invalidated. While error messages should be displayed when any of the respective input controls is invalidated. Here is my code snippet.

```js
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#date").datePicker();
            });
          
          var myApp = angular.module("myApp",[]);
            myApp.controller('myController', function($scope){
                $scope.submitForm = function() {

                // check to make sure the form is completely valid
                if ($scope.myForm.$valid) {
                    alert('our form is amazing');
                }

            }
            });
```

```html
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

            <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <form novalidate name="myForm" ng-submit="submitForm()" >
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Username</label>
                                <input type="text" name="username" ng-minLength="3" ng-maxLength="10" placeholder="type your username" class="form-control" required></input>
                                <p ng-show="myForm.username.$error.$pristine" class="help-block">Username is required.</p>
                                <p ng-show="myForm.username.$error.minlength" class="help-block">Username is too short.</p>
                                <p ng-show="myForm.username.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">Username is too long.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Email</label>
                                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="type your valid email" ng-pattern="^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$" class="form-control" required></input>
                                <p ng-show="myForm.email.$error.$pristine" class="help-block">email is required.</p>
                                <p ng-show="myForm.email.$error.$pattern" class="help-block">Please enter valid email</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Password</label>
                                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="type your password"  class="form-control" required></input>
                                <p ng-show="myForm.password.$error.$pristine" class="help-block">password is required.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Date of Birth</label>
                                <input type="dob" name="dob" placeholder="type your valid Date of Birth" ng-pattern="^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$" class="form-control" required></input>
                                <p ng-show="myForm.dob.$error.$pristine" class="help-block">Date of Birth is required.</p>
                                <p ng-show="myForm.dob.$error.$pattern" class="help-block">Please enter valid Date of Birth</p>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" action="/register" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! You should be more precise about your problems so that we can help you. Describing what your code should do is a good start, but we must know what it currently does. What exactly is "not working as expected"? Are there errors in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For angular validation you must required ng-model on input types check updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UT0yLhTNLGpsAlq5k2MZ?p=preview) here,

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Form Validation Demo</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#date").datePicker();
    });
  </script>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <form novalidate name="myForm" ng-submit="submitForm()">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Username</label>
              <input type="text" name="username" ng-model="username" minLength="3" maxLength="10" placeholder="type your username" class="form-control" required />
              <span ng-show="myForm.username.$error.required" class="help-block">Username is required.</span>
              <p ng-show="myForm.username.$error.minlength" class="help-block">Username is too short.</p>
              <p ng-show="myForm.username.$error.maxlength" class="help-block">Username is too long.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Email</label>
              <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" placeholder="type your valid email" ng-pattern="^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$" class="form-control" required />
              <p ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required" class="help-block">email is required.</p>
              <p ng-show="myForm.email.$error.$pattern" class="help-block">Please enter valid email</p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Password</label>
              <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="type your password" class="form-control" required />
              <p ng-show="myForm.password.$error.required" class="help-block">password is required.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Date of Birth</label>
              <input type="dob" name="dob" ng-model="dob" placeholder="type your valid Date of Birth" ng-pattern="^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$" class="form-control" required />
              <p ng-show="myForm.dob.$error.required" class="help-block">Date of Birth is required.</p>
              <p ng-show="myForm.dob.$error.$pattern" class="help-block">Please enter valid Date of Birth</p>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" action="/register" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
    myApp.controller('myController', function($scope) {
      $scope.submitForm = function() {

        // check to make sure the form is completely valid
        if ($scope.myForm.$valid) {
          alert('our form is amazing');
        }

      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

may this help you.
Thanks

Comment: Hi @Ajay  I have cleared my doubt. You are most welcome. Much appreciated.